# Does a range convert to bool via emtpy() member function when used as a if condition?

Tags: c++, if-statement, c++14, range-v3, conversion-operator

The following code compiles, runs, and gives the result as if `range` is being converted to `bool` via `range.empty()`. Is it actually what happens? I'm really not comfortable enough in navigating Range-v3 headers, so I'm asking this question here.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/view/take.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/drop.hpp>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::vector<int> v{1};
    if (auto range = v | ranges::views::take(1)) {
        std::cout << "take" << std::endl;
    }
    if (auto range = v | ranges::views::drop(1)) {
        std::cout << "drop" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *only* operations required for a type to fit the `std::ranges::range` concept (or its Range-v3 equivalent) is being able to perform `std::ranges::begin`/`end` on it (or its Range-v3 equivalent). But this does not mean that a range type only has those operations.

A type that fits a concept can implement anything it wants on top of that. So while the `range` concept does not specify the functionality you're seeing, it would be valid for any particular type that satisfies `range` to provide it.

So the question you're really asking is whether these particular range view types provide such an operator. The answer is [yes, according to the documentation](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/structranges_1_1view__interface.html#a4138fd9cecb78b536dc871c0de0e1326). The `view_interface` type provides an `explicit operator bool` if the underlying range is a type for which empty testing is allowed. And for what it's worth, so does the C++20 equivalent.